# How to make an app with administrator rights in C# using Wix Installer without UAC prompt when runs

Tags: c#, .net, wix, installation, uac

I need help please!

I need my `.exe` to always run as administrator without UAC prompt (I don't need to turn off the UAC, but just to allow my program). My program will be installed with a `.msi installer` developed in WIX, which will have for one time admin rights, and I need to perform such step but I don't know where, in this setup or in the `.cs program` that my exe will be always executed as admin without UAC prompt.

I've read a lot about Windows UAC and there the most expensive way is buying a certificate for my app, but without this I know that can be done because there are many apps that doesn't have this certificate and they work fine.

I've found different solutions but without a clear answer, because a windows service together with my program is installed and then the program can start, stop and disable this windows service. That's why changing the installation directory of my program doesn't help.

I tried adding a `manifest` file to my startup project, where I wrote `requireAdministrator` but still apearing this prompt. Texting `asInvoker`the prompt does not appear but then my application does not run because requires administrator rights.

Another way is adding a `.bat` file with this code:

`cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" %1"`

I tried with the `registry` as the example [here](http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2018/06/28/zapusk-programmy-bez-prav-admina-i-zaprosa-uac/) and it works but it doesn't with my `.exe`. Even if I make an entry into the `registry` with the same code.

There is a solution using the Task Schedule but I don't need this way.

Is there a clear solution? Maybe some other entries into the `registry`?

Thanks.

Comment: I really mean no offense but whatever you are trying to do here, you are going about the wrong way.
UAC exists for a reason.  Elevating privileges without UAC is something you really aren't supposed to do (even if you CAN doesn't mean that you SHOULD).
With that said... if you insist of doing things the wrong way, check out this post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt

Comment: Is it only the service management that you need admin rights for? [Maybe see this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5752.how-to-grant-users-rights-to-manage-services-start-stop-etc.aspx).

Comment: You can use your service to do whatever needs administrator permissions.
As a user I would be very unhappy if an application runs with administrator privileges without asking me for it, as this shows me that something is corrupt in my windows installation. As writing this, I remember that most of the time someone asks for always running his application with administrator permissions these permissions were not really needed - think about it, if this might be true for you and maybe change your application accordingly.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul  I checked that does not work for windows 10

Comment: @FlorianHaupt Is uncofortable that everytime when launch the .exe appears that prompt. So my program does not do anything bad just I need the service to start programs automatically since I turn on the computer without log in, that's the function of my service. My program just Start, Stop, Disable this service and the configuration: Manually, Automatic, etc. I don't need a Task Schedule. If you know the way, it will be helpful

Comment: @ErickMaldonado A way I could think of, after your described behavior, is to install another service, that does nothing else than configuration on your service. Another way might be, to let your existing service always start, let it read a configuration file and let it act according to the configuration in the file - your program will then have to handle these configuration file settings.